# Vue: modify props of slotted component programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

## Question

How does one modify a `prop` of a slotted Element at runtime?

Do I use the wrong lifecycle methods?
Are changes to `slottedElement.type.props` necessary as well?

## Example

A.vue

```
<template>
    <B key="tag-outer">
        <B key="tag-inner" />
    </B>
</template>

<script>
import B from "./B.vue";

export default {
    name: "A",
    components: {
        B,
    },
};
</script>
```

B.vue

```
<template>
    <p>{{ mode }}</p>
    <slot />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "B",

    props: {
        mode: {
            type: String,
            default: "outer",
        },

        key: String,
    },

    computed: {
        hasSlot() {
            return !!this.$slots.default;
        },
    },

    beforeMount() {
        this.modifySlottedElements();
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
        this.modifySlottedElements();
    },

    methods: {
        modifySlottedElements() {
            if (this.hasSlot) {
                this.$slots.default().forEach((slottedElement) => {
                    if (slottedElement.type.name === "B") {
                        // prevent concurrency issues
                        const copiedSlottedElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(slottedElement));
                        console.log("before");
                        console.log(copiedSlottedElement);

                        slottedElement.props.mode = "inner";

                        console.log("modified");
                        console.log(slottedElement);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

## Output

```
before

type = Object {name: "B", props: Object, computed: Object, methods: Object, __file: "C:/dev/git/csx-vue/src/demo/test/B.vue", ...}
props = Object {key: "tag-inner"}
...
```

```
modified

type = Object {name: "B", props: Object, computed: Object, beforeMount: Function, beforeUpdate: Function, ...}
props = Object {key: "tag-inner", mode: "inner"}
...
```

## Rendered

```
<p>outer</p>
<p>outer</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efc1z89j/)

Thank you

---

## Workaround

Using an inverted logic (checking the parent)

```
<template>
    <p>{{ modeProxy }}</p>
    <slot />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "B",

    props: {
        mode: {
            type: String,
            default: "outer",
        },

        key: String,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            modeProxy: this.mode,
        };
    },

    beforeMount() {
        this.markSubMenu();
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
        this.markSubMenu();
    },

    methods: {
        markSubMenu() {
            if (this.$parent.$.type.name === "B") {
                this.modeProxy = "inner";
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have to clarify the use-case in your example in order to provide a good solution. As of right now it seems you want to modify the props of the slotted component depending on it's type. But the example indicates you just want to make it aware that it's in an "inner" context. Why don't you just pass down this information via a prop?

Comment: Context: a navigation menu

Submenus need some differences and setting the prop manually works perfectly fine.
As a convenience feature it would be nice if you could simply stack these elements and the entry itself takes care of defining its level / depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to solve your problem is to use [inject/provide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject)

1. Your menu component will use `inject` to get it's level from the parent (if there is one)
2. and `provide` to provide the information about the level for it's child components

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Level: {{ menuLevel }} / {{ menuLevel2 }}
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { provide, inject } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'NestedMenu',
  setup() {
    // using Composition API
    let menuLevel = inject('menuLevel', 1 /* this is default value */);
    provide('menuLevel', menuLevel + 1);

    return { menuLevel };
  },
  // Same functionality as above but using Options API
  inject: {
    menuLevel2: { default: 1 },
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      menuLevel2: this.menuLevel2 + 1,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```